# Array is an object of which class exactly

Tags: java

If array in java is an object, then as per OOPS principle only classes can have objects. So my question is array are actually objects of which class?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8

Comment: An array is not an instance of a class, it is a language construct with the functionality to hold a collection/a list of elements of a certain type

Comment: @devnull69 "An array is not an instance of a class" False. Try calling `someArray.getClass()` or `new String[0] instanceof String[]`.

Comment: Ok if you have an array instance, you can get its class and you can verify its type. But the array construct is not a class instance per se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [JLS Sec 10.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8):

> Every array has an associated Class object, shared with all other arrays with the same component type.
>
> Although an array type is not a class, the Class object of every array acts as if:
>
> - The direct superclass of every array type is Object.
> - Every array type implements the interfaces Cloneable and java.io.Serializable.

A `String[]` is an instance of `String[].class`; an `int[]` is an instance of `int[].class` etc. And these are different classes from `String.class` and `int.class`.

But there is no "`Array`" superclass of all arrays, as described in the first bullet: both `String[]` and `int[]` are direct subclasses of `Object`.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/ZrkNG1)

Comment: So how come in most of the reference books is it mentioned that array is an object and no further discussions are there.

Comment: @AnuragDubey that's not untrue: arrays are reference types, and so they are subclasses of `Object`. They probably omit the further details to keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks. I too had doubts regarding String[], int[] etc. How can we know what the methods of these classes are, as I could not find any java API for the same. @AndyTurner

Comment: There is no Javadoc as such, but the members are described in [JLS Sec 10.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7).

Comment: @AndyTurner Can u go through this and explain what exactly this part of document says. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1

Comment: @AnuragDubey that's too broad a question. I don't know what you don't understand about it.